# Google Drive revoke permissions on shared files

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I want to revoke permissions on a shared file on my Google Drive Account.

```
 String fileId = "abc1234";
  String permissionId = "abc1234";
try 
{
  service.permissions().delete(fileId, permissionId).execute();
}//try
catch (IOException e) 
{
  System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
}//catch
```

I think the problem here might be the permissionId's value. Does anyone know how can get the right one? Also, is this the right way to revoke someone's permissions on a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing a [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list)

```
service.permissions().list(fileId).execute();
```

This will return a list of the permission on the file in question.  Then you can find the permission that you want to delete and run your delete on that.